# data is not insert in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am beginner of nodejs and mongodb. I am inserting data to collection using mongoose ORM and model but not insert. Validation is working correct but data is not insert after filling complete data. I have not create collection in database manually. should I create collection manually in mongodb or create automatically when inserting document.

productsController

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = require('../config/db_config');
var Product = require('../models/product');
//var Product = mongoose.model('Products');
var productController = {};

productController.add = function(req, res) {
    var params = req.body;

    if(!params) {
        res.status(400).send({message: "Data can not be empty"});
    }

    var productData = new Product({
        product_name : params.product_name,
        price : params.price,
        category : params.category
    });

    console.log(productData);

    productData.save(function(err, product) {
        if (err){
          res.status(400).send({message:'Unable to save data! ' + err});
        }else{
            res.status(200).send({message:'Data has been saved! ' + product });
        }
    });
};

module.exports = productController;
```

Models code is here

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = require('../config/db_config');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var productSchema = new Schema({

  product_name: { type: String, required:  'Product name cannot be left blank.' },

  price:    { type: String,     required:  'Product price cannot be left blank.'},

  category: { type: String ,    required:  'Product category cannot be left blank'},

  updated_at : {type: Date, default: Date.now}

});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Products', productSchema);
```

routes file code is here:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Product = require('../models/product.js');
var productsController = require('../controllers/productsController');

router.post('/add',productsController.add);

module.exports = router;
```

DB config file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeweb', function(err,db){
    if(err){
        throw err;
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to database!');
    }
});
module.exports = db;
```

I have insert controller, model and routes file code.

Comment: what is the erroe ?

Comment: @Bunny Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.(anonymous function) [as get] (/var/www/html/nodejs/nodeweb/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:202:15)

Comment: @OmodemiladeBamgbose i have changed Required to required, but still not working.

Comment: Can you show, please entire routers file? Seems the error is there.

Comment: @ArtemBardachov 
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Product = require('../models/product.js');
var productsController = require('../controllers/productsController');

router.get('/products',productsController.products);
router.post('/add',productsController.add);
module.exports = router;

Comment: Edit your question with full code, then only we can find the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your method -

Controller function

```
exports.add = function(req, res) {
  var new_product = new Products(req.body);  
   // you have define Products not Product
  console.log(new_product);
  new_product.save(function(err, product) {
    console.log('add data');
    if (err){
      res.send(err);
    }else{
        res.json(product);
    }
  });

};
```

and for good practice in node js - i think you can start with [express-app-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-app-generator)

This Helps to make simple routing, with generic responses and in-built express middlewares with loggers.

Comment: I have used var Product = mongoose.model('Products'); in controller file. so i can not write Products

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved problem. database connection work with connect method.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/nodeweb', {useMongoClient: true}, function(err,db){
    if(err){
        throw err;
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('Successfully connected to database!');
    }
});
```